# Save custom product input to database in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, field

I use the following code to the database:

```
$attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$title_top_R_0 = isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] ) ? $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] : '';
$attribute_R_0->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title_related', sanitize_text_field( $title_top_R_0 ) );
$attribute_R_0->save();
```

but I want to use a condition to avoid creating a blank table in db, which one is correct? A or B?

A:

```
if ('custom_text_field_title_related') {
    $attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $title_top_R_0 = isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] ) ? $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] : '';
    $attribute_R_0->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title_related', sanitize_text_field( $title_top_R_0 ) );
    $attribute_R_0->save();
}
```

B:

```
$attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$nui_1 = $attribute_14->get_meta( 'custom_text_field_title_related' );
if ($nui_1 ){
$title_top_R_0 = isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] ) ? $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] : '';
$attribute_R_0->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title_related', sanitize_text_field( $title_top_R_0 ) );
$attribute_R_0->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them… To avoid a blank entry in database table, you should use instead:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] ) ) {
    $attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $attribute_R_0->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title_related', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_related'] ) );
    $attribute_R_0->save();
}
```

or better:

```
$field_key_R_0 = 'custom_text_field_title_related';

if ( isset( $_POST[$field_key_R_0] ) && ! empty( $_POST[$field_key_R_0] ) ) {
    $attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $attribute_R_0->update_meta_data( $field_key_R_0, sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field_key_R_0] ) );
    $attribute_R_0->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec , in case that I have several custom input, is it crucial to repeat `$attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );` ?

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei No only one time for all related product inputs that belongs to that product. You should name `$attribute_R_0`as `$product` or `$_product`

Comment: I use the second method, but when I delete the text box, the content that I already input is not deleted. for example, while I adding a product I type in the checkbox, after that when I am going to delete it and update the product information, the text I put is remaining.

Comment: should I use `else {delete_post_meta( $id, 'custom_text_field_title_related' );}` ?

Comment: it works: `else {
    $attribute_R_0 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $attribute_R_0 = delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_text_field_category_pills_4' );
 }`